Two PayPal Buttons On One Page in React
I am trying to render two PayPal no-code buttons on my webpage (e.g. Services Page) They both take different amounts, $ 49 and $ 1000.
Because its implementation in React is a little bit different from HTML, I assume there is an issue whereby the two are clashing and only one is rendered on a reload.
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/services' element={<ServicesPage />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage />} />
        <Route path='/extra' element={<ExtraPage />} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<ContactPage />} />
      </Routes>
      <div className="container">
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ServicesPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title subTitle='Our Services' title='What We Offer' />
      <Services />
      <PayPalButton />
    </div>
  );
}

const PayPalButton = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load PayPal SDK script (only one time)
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT-ID&components=hosted-buttons&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Render PayPal hosted button after script is loaded
    script.onload = () => {

      //Render first PayPal Button
      window.paypal.HostedButtons({
        hostedButtonId: "CLIENT-ID",
      }).render("#paypal-container");

      //Render second PayPal Button
      window.paypal.HostedButtons({
        hostedButtonId: "CLIENT-ID",
      }).render("#paypal-container1");
};

    // Cleanup function to remove script after component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Container for PayPal button */}
      <div id="paypal-container" className="paypal-buttons"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title subTitle='About Us' title='Who We Are' />
      <About />
    </div>
  );
}

const ExtraPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title subTitle='Extra Services' title='Our Rental Services' />
      <Extra />
    </div>
  );
}

const ContactPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title subTitle='Contact Us' title='Get In Touch' />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I have tried changing the container id names, but to no avail. Still, only one PayPal button shows up.
I tried creating two separate components (PayPalButton, PayPalButton 1) and importing them in the App.js, and adding the imports under "Services Page", but to no avail. Still, only one PayPal button shows up.
However, If I delete the PayPalButton1 content and render a new rafce content it renders both the paypal button from "PayPalButton" and the random text from "PayPalButton1".

The problem is you're loading the PayPal script twice (once for each button).
You must load the PayPal script only once per page load (any subsequent loads are redundant and will conflict)
In the script.onload function where you first render a button, add code to render the second button to the other container.
Something like this (only one time, no second one for PayPalButton1)
const PayPalButton = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load PayPal SDK script (only one time)
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT-ID&components=hosted-buttons&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Render PayPal hosted button after script is loaded
    script.onload = () => {

      //Render first PayPal Button
      window.paypal.HostedButtons({
        hostedButtonId: "CLIENT-ID",
      }).render("#paypal-container");

      //Render second PayPal Button
      window.paypal.HostedButtons({
        hostedButtonId: "CLIENT-ID",
      }).render("#paypal-container1"); 
};

    // Cleanup function to remove script after component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Container for PayPal button */}
      <div id="paypal-container" className="paypal-buttons"></div>
    </div>
  );
}



I really appreciate your feedback. I would be glad, if you can help me with the revised version of the code for only the "script.onload" section.

If you want others to be able to easily read and work with your code, you should not post images of it. Use code blocks and post in text form only

Thanks for your feedback. I would do exactly that.

Please, I have updated the content as you instructed. I would be glad if you could assist me with the revised version because I'm struggling with it.  Thank you

Done. Hopefully the Same client-id is being used in both cases and the only thing different is the hostedButtonId.

Thanks for your feedback. I'm very much grateful.  I'll update you on the outcome.

After adding the revised version, I realized that only the first PayPal Button is rendered after every reload.  Let me ask, is it impossible to have  2 PayPal  Buttons of the same clientid on one page.

I have added the revised version for your perusal. I would be very grateful if there are other means of communication that we can use to enable me fix the problem. Because the PayPal integration seems to be the only aspect left.
